# Show that if $\int_S \varphi d\mu<\infty$, $E=\{x\in S: \varphi(x)<\infty\}$, then $\mu(E^c)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The Problem arises from Walter Rudin's *Real & Complex Analysis*:
[image]

Now, I understand that $E^c=S^c\cup A$, where $A=\{x\in S: \varphi(x)=\infty\}$; thus I tried to show that:

1. $A\in\mathfrak{M}$;
2. $\mu(A)=0$.

Because then we'd have $\mu(E^c)=\mu(S^c)+\mu(A)=0+0=0$, since $A\cap S^c=\emptyset$; but I failed on both attempts. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint.

Let $E_n = \{x\in S : \varphi(x) > n\}$. Then $E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, and $\mu(E_1) \le \int_S\varphi\,d\mu < \infty$, by (4). Now it suffices to show that $\mu(E_n)\to 0$ (why?).